# SharedPreferences does not show types or all of the Preferences form the XML

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, edittextpreference

When I look at the map returning from get all, I can see only the values that were set before as a hashmap and I cannot cast to EditTextPreference.

Its looks like getAll() is getting the preference hash but not the types from the XML

What I am trying to do is set the summary for a preference to the value.

```
public static class Prefs1Fragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.initial_preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        Map<String, ?> preferencesMap = sharedPreferences.getAll();
        String appId = sharedPreferences.getString(PabuloConstants.InternalAppIdPerfName, "N/A");
        // iterate through the preference entries and update their summary if they are an instance of EditTextPreference
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> preferenceEntry : preferencesMap.entrySet()) {
            if(preferenceEntry instanceof EditTextPreference){
                Log.d("","found instance");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Category Title">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="app_id_preference"
        android:title="some title"
        android:summary="some summary"
        />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="app_id_preference2"
        android:title="some title"
        android:summary="some summary"
        />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="app_id_preference3"
        android:title="some title"
        android:summary="some summary"
        />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: `preferencesMap.entrySet()` stores Strings, not the strings that added those views. I don't think anything will be an instance of an EditTextPrefference

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the right way of doing this is by calling findPreference with the key